# Binding multiple select froms together

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a form that fills out a table in my database and I have different selects that represent different columns of a database table "orgine". I want when I select origine.codearticle to display in the other selections origine.nature,origine.n_phase... the values that have the same value of origine.codearticle i.e. as if I apply a filter in the selection.

[Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HcRI.png)

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqEDC.png)

[typescripte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHStL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand your question, you want to set a filter on the toggle menus on the bottom after you've chosen the Code Article. I saw your html code, which looks fine, though nothing happens if you chose an option.

HTML

```
...
   <select (change)="changeOtherToggles()" required [(ngModel)]="fnc.codeart" name="codeart">
         ...
   </select>
...
```

TypeScript

```
...
changeOtherToggles() {
   switch(fnc.codeart) {
      case(statement): {
       // here you can change the lists of the other toggles
       break;
      }
      // other cases
   }
   
}
...
```

I added a `(change)="changeOtherToggles()"` to the `<select>`, so the elements of the other toggle menus can be changed in your function.